# Retain the placeholder after typing

Tags: html, css, placeholder, floating

I've 2 input fields with floating placeholders. On focus, the placeholder moves up and creates space for the user to type. But it disappears as soon as the user starts to input. I want the placeholder to stay in the same place after typing something in the text box. Is this possible by using only CSS?

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #343a40;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99%, #007bff 1%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99%, #007bff 1%);
  background-position: -1000px 0;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #000;
}

input:focus,
input:valid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #007bff;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Username" type="text" required>
<input placeholder="Password" type="password" required>
```

Comment: Use a label instead of a placeholder and style the label

Comment: Not really, because once the input has any content, the placeholder is not shown any more. You could perhaps achieve this, if you used labels instead of placeholder - [placeholders are considered harmful anyway](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/). But, to be fair - [so is the floating label pattern](https://medium.com/simple-human/floating-labels-are-a-bad-idea-82edb64220f6). So if accessibility is your focus, and not just designer's vanity ... then you should perhaps not use either of those.

Comment: That really make sense.. Thanks @CBroe

Answer (score 2):

as commented you should use a `label`. *Also properly connected to its input to be coherent*.

https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

> The `<label>` element represents a caption in a user interface.
>
> - HTML Attribute **for = string**
>
> Specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated.
>   The attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable form-associated element in the same Document as the label element.
>
> Example: `<input type="checkbox" id="lost" name="lost"> <label for="lost">Lost</label>`

from there, setting the `label` right after the input, it will be stylable via the `+` selector.

CSS example

```css
label {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1.75em;/*climbs under the input */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;/* set input on top of label. opaque white bg color can be used to lighten label's color */
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #343a40;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99%,
    #007bff 1%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99%, #007bff 1%)
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-position: -1000px 0;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: transparent;/* hide value if any when label is standing here too */
}
input:focus {
  color: #000;
}
input:valid + label {
  color: #06a31b;
  z-index: 1;/* let's show this field is filled */
}
input:focus + label, input:active + label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #007bff;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-2em);/* move it up more */
}

input:focus,
input:valid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="" id="User" type="text" required><label for="User">Username</label>
<input id="pwd" placeholder="" type="password" required><label for="pwd">Password</label>
```

Other CSS example where label stands at top once field filled

```css
label {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1.75em;/*climbs under the input */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;/* set input on top of label. opaque white bg color can be used to lighten label's color */
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #343a40;
 transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background:linear-gradient(
    to top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99%,
    #007bff 1%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99%, #007bff 1%)
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-position: -1000px 0;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
input:focus {
  color: #000;
}
input:valid + label,
input:focus + label, input:active + label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #007bff;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-2em);/* move it up more */
}

input:focus,
input:valid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="" id="User" type="text" required><label for="User">Username</label>
<input id="pwd" placeholder="" type="password" required><label for="pwd">Password</label>
```

For infos: `:valid/:invalid` is CSS selector level 4 still at draft state https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#validity-pseudos but yet well inplemented  http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Avalid